Enable cross-region automated backup replication for Multi-AZ RDS Aurora Cluster
I have a question regarding implementing cross-region automated backups replication for RDS Aurora Postgres cluster in Terraform (ideally using 'internal' RDS service functionalities /API endpoints).
Using the terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws I created a Multi-AZ RDS Cluster with autoscaling enabled (min. 1 read-replica).
Is there a way to implement the cross-region automated backups replication in terraform without the need to e.g. manually snapshot the DB Cluster and then replicate it to another region or the need to utilize another AWS service like Backup?
There's the aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication resource which I guess I might configure to set the source_db_instance_arn attr. to point to the primary aka writer Instance of the Cluster but I wonder how the system would behave if e.g. there'd be temporal outage in the writer's AZ and Cluster nominates new primary.
The overall goal is to come up with a relatively inexpensive disaster recovery setup in case of rare region-scale AWS incident, therefore I assumed that warm cross-region cluster replicas or Aurora Global Databases are a bit of an overkill.

According to these resources:
#1 and
#2
'Automated backup replication is not supported for Multi-AZ DB clusters.' therefore there is no internal RDS means to enable such functionality aka one would need to either manually manage and replicate cluster snapshots or turn to e.g. AWS Backup service
